# Getting javascript is disabled after launching the application

Tags: javascript, firefoxdriver

Whenever I launch our application, in the Welcome.do page I am getting the javascript disabled message however when I check the about:config, I can see that the configuration is set to javascript.enabled = true. The only difference is that this particular configuration is un-editable. Does it have an effect when launching the app?